# Is there any canonical information regarding a battle between Hogwarts founder(s) and a Dark wizard?

Tags: harry-potter

I have a VERY vague recollection of reading about a fight/battle/war between a group of magic users and a Dark wizard, with the former including one/some/all of Hogwarts founders.

I was NEVER able to find a reference to such an event in any resource, so I'm ready to chalk it down to having seen it in one of the few fanfics I bothered to read.

Is there any canonical information regarding a conflict between Hogwarts founder(s) and a Dark wizard?

As an aside - if the answer is "no" and it was from a fanfic, does anyone know which fanfic it was in? (I only ever read a couple of really long ones limited to post-GOF time, so applicable set is probably not very large).

Comment: Maybe you are messing this up with Hogwarts _headmasters_?

Comment: @sbi - no. I am not.

Comment: Not the founders fighting *among* themselves?

Comment: @BorhanMooz - nope.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Hmm... Thinking...

Comment: NOTE: Someone posted a (really poor and now-deleted) answer a while back stating it was HP and Methods of Rationality fic. I can 100% certainly state that this was NOT MoR fic since I didn't yet start reading it and don't know any of its plot aside from the main premise.

Comment: Could you be thinking of a Fan fiction? In the second James Potter Jr fan fiction he travels back through time and witnesses the battle between the hogwarts founders and slytherin :)

Comment: @CandiedMango - as the second paragraph attests to, quite possibly

Comment: @DVK Do you happen to remember anything about Merlin being around? and Mirrors being involved?

Comment: @CandiedMango - no and no

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have read and re-read the series, though not the *Tales of Beedle the Bard* or other works Rowling has written for charity, and have not found any references to this (though it has been a while, so it could have slipped my mind).

I've also been unable to find any references to such a battle in any of the various Harry Potter wikis I've found.

I believe the Potterverse canon is contained entirely within the books (or the movies, for the Potter movieverse).  Thus, I think I can safely say, "**No.  No such battle is canonically referenced.**"

I haven't read any HP fanfiction that involves such a battle, either.  In fact, I haven't read much in the way of HP fanfics at all.

Comment: I share DVKs recollection, but I think it's to do with slytheren being kick out of hogwarts?